# codenameone: how to handle exception java.net.ConnectionException explicitly

Tags: codenameone

codenameone: how to handle exception java.net.ConnectionException explicitly 
I want to handle exception explicitly.Currently when I am handling exception It handled implicitly first in which shows the exception message on screen in detail.I don't want to show in detail error message on screen(pop up dialog).
right now it shows the exception Java.net.Connection Exception: Connection refused for URL http:localhost/login connection refused.instead of this message i just want to show "connection refused" message on pop-up dialog

Can you please let me know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mobile devices the error might be quite different to the one on the simulator since we are dealing with native API's under the surface. See the error handling section of the [networking section in the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html):

There are two distinct placed where you can handle a networking error:

- The `ConnectionRequest` - by overriding callback methods
- The `NetworkManager` error handler

Notice that the `NetworkManager` error handler takes precedence thus allowing you to define a global policy for network error handling by consuming errors.

E.g. if I would like to block all network errors from showing anything to the user I could do something like this:

```
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
NetworkManager.getInstance().addErrorListener((e) -> e.consume());
```

The error listener is invoked first with the NetworkEvent matching the error. Consuming the event prevents it from propagating further down the chain into the ConnectionRequest callbacks.

We can also override the error callbacks of the various types in the request e.g. in the case of a server error code we can do:

```
ConnectionRequest request = new ConnectionRequest(url, false) {
    protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
        if(code == 444) {
            // do something
        }
    }
    protected void handleException(Exception err) {
        // handle exception that occurred. Notice you can either have this or have the listener on the NetworkManager
    }
    protected void readResponse(InputStream input) {
        // just read from the response input stream
    }
};
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
```

Comment: how to handle timeout exception of ConnectionRequest class ?

Comment: It will manifest itself either in the error listener/the `handleException` method.

Comment: can you explain it with example?

Comment: The examples above cover it, I refined it slightly

Comment: That's a server side error (500) so there isn't much you can do other than present an error to the user.

Comment: There is no exception on the client side. It's a server side exception on the mobile device you get a 500 error code. You need to handle the exception on your server! Look in your server logs.